# Can’t find Desktop folder in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have recently re-installed Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook on my machine and now when I launch Jupyter, I can’t find my ’Desktop’, ’Downloads’, ’Documents’ maps that were usually there at the start page. There isn’t any ’Users’ or ’C:/’ maps either, and I can’t find my way to my notebooks that are located on my Desktop. Instead it is showing a lot of .dll files and weird sounding maps. How do I navigate to the map that I need in Jupyter?

Comment: I think you're running Jupyter from a different folder than you used to. It looks like you used to run it from `C:/` and now you're running it from somewhere else like a much deeper folder. If you run it from a top directory you should see them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Anaconda Prompt to navigate to the `'C:/'` folder (or any other folder you want) and then launch `jupyter notebook` from there.

In the Anaconda Prompt try:

```
(base) C:\Users\Ale>cd "C:/"
(base) C:\>jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Sure. It was an example since the current folder is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same issue. I bought a new laptop and was downloading Anaconda into this one whilst the day before I installed OneDrive placing Desktop under my Onedrive. This managed to put it on OneDrive. So I found my Desktop in the Onedrive folder on Jupyter Notebook.

(Just thought someone else might have had the same situation)